# java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.ScrollView$SavedState

Tags: android, android-view, androidx

I recently started getting following exception in our production app.

{
  "androidApiLevel": "28",
  "osBuild": "PQ2A.190405.003"
}

Device: Pixel 2 XL

Any idea whats going on here?

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.view.AbsSavedState$1 cannot be cast to android.widget.ScrollView$SavedState
    at android.widget.ScrollView.onRestoreInstanceState(ScrollView.java:1834)
    at android.view.View.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(View.java:18608)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3821)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3827)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchRestoreInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:3827)
    at android.view.View.restoreHierarchyState(View.java:18586)
    at androidx.e.a.d.restoreViewState(Fragment.java:494)
    at androidx.e.a.j.a(FragmentManager.java:1486)
    at androidx.e.a.j.f(FragmentManager.java:1784)
    at androidx.e.a.j.a(FragmentManager.java:1852)
    at androidx.e.a.j.e(FragmentManager.java:3269)
    at androidx.e.a.j.q(FragmentManager.java:3229)
    at androidx.e.a.g.f(FragmentController.java:201)
    at androidx.e.a.e.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:620)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.d.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:178)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1391)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7165)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:2975)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:180)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:165)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:142)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:70)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1816)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6718)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:-2)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
```

Comment: add your line of code  which was given error so we can help

Answer (score 2):

There might be a case where you are using the same ID name for two elements.

Recheck the ID which you have assigned to the scrollview with other views

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by going through the children of the scroll view and assigning id for them programmatically:

```
child.setId(generateViewId());
```

You can iterate them with the `getChildCount()` and `getChildAt()` etc.